# Application using machine learning to auto-correct custom sentences: how to begin?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, bison, flex-lexer, error-correction

Before asking my question, here is the situation:

I have some very basic knowledge about Artifical Intelligence, I know about Inference Engine, coding in LISP or Prolog, a bit about neural network, but not much. That's what I studied.

I have a project, an application which has to correct some custom sentences.

Those sentences are normal strings, which can contain a lot of different characters. Fortunately, thanks to Flex(lexer), I defined Tokens, which is now easier for analysis. An example of string:

```
AZERTY AWESOME 333.222 AZERTY MAGIC P
```

Which gives in tokens (example):

```
VERB NOUN NUMBER VERB ADJECTIVE SPEC
```

I also use Bison to allow some combos, and reject the others:

```
VERB NOUN NUMBER VERB ADJECTIVE SPEC is ok
VERB VERB NOUN NUMBER  ADJECTIVE SPEC is not ok
etc...
```

Those sentences can have some errors when coming to my application. These errors can be from different origins, let's have some examples:

```
AZERTY AWESOM E 333.222 AZERTY MAGIC POINT
```

Additionnal space in the word awesome makes the parser to recognize a VERB and a SPEC instead of NOUN (like above). So the correction would be to remove the additionnal space.

Others errors can be a missing space (making stick two words), unknown tokens, unknown combo (for bison), no spaces at all, etc...

So I began to create my application in C++, with a determinist approach first: I created a kind of dictionnary which contains every pattern of error I found previously, and created corrections for them. It works quite well, I can correct a lot of them because I found very generic pattern. But I would like to enhance this performance by adding a machine learning feature, to correct the other ones.

I have let's say 70% of correction good with my "fixed-correction", and I would like to make this % grow up with a machine learning thing. It would learn from wrong&corrected sentences, and then would be able to correct by itself the sentences I wasn't able to correct (the last 30%).

Here is my question, I am a newbie in machine learning, even if I have already studied AI a bit, and I don't know where to begin.

My first question is: I know about neural network, but it is used to guess, right? For example, I would give it a sentence and it would be able to tell me if it's correct or not. But this is not what I want, I want the app to correct it, not just telling if it's correct. The thing is I don't really see how the application can "remove/modify" by itself.

In which direction would you suggest that I would go for ? Which Machine Learning Principles/ Tools / Technologies would you suggest for this kind of application?

I hope you understood my problem well, and will be able to help me.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary? Do strings have to be real words? I assume there is no way to tell if for example "awe some" is an error or not.

Comment: This is where, I think, machine learning can change things. By learning wrong & corrected sentences, it would see that even if "awe some" is possible, it is used normally as "awesome".

Comment: I think the standard approach is to build a sort of Markov Model where for each two words A,B you have a probability of seeing the combination A B in a sentence. You then use the probability of seeing an error to calculate whether it is more likely that the sentence was supposed to be A B as two words or as one. The hard part is building the model.

Comment: The "whitespace" error is an error that I can usually solve with my first solution. But this idea is quite interesting. I still just don't see how the application could correct that "by itself".

Comment: You basically have many different options for what the correct sentence should be. You can build these options by first assuming no errors then assume one error and build all possible sentences with one error and so on. You can then calculate the probability of seeing each of these sentences given the original sentence and choose the sentece with the highest probability.

Comment: Where should I begin ? What tools are best ? I know I will have (for sure) to deal with probabilities, but I need at least some hints

Answer (score 1):

Well since no other answers were posted and Benjy Kessler didn't sum up his link, I decided to post my own answer, if it can help someone.

I decided to use the N-grams strategy which is, I think, a good way to solve my problem. It is just theory, and I began coding this, but it may not work. But I like the idea and I think it is worth a try.

N-grams are UNIGRAM (a word), or a BIGRAM (pair of words) or a TRIGRAM (three words), etc... etc..

The main idea is to give my application a lot of training data, with good-format strings. For each of them, I'm going to count the n-grams (from uni to tri).

I will get then something like this (after giving the app thousands of data):

unigram table (figures are fake and random)

```
     word     |  occurrence  |   prob 
 ________________________________________
     I        |     500      |   0.2 
     want     |     645      |   0.2 
     a        |    2434      |   0.5 
     cat      |      20      |   0.1
```

bigram table

```
 first word    |   second word   |  occurrence  |   prob 
 ___________________________________________________________
 |    I        |     want       |      600      |    0.5   
 |    want     |     a          |      500      |    0.4   
 |    a        |     cat        |      100      |    0.1
```

same for trigram table.

So when I have this data, it is easier then to analyse, let's have an example:

```
 I WANTA CAT
```

When analysing, the app will see first that WANTA doesn't exist in the table, so it will split this word until it gets a "sentence" with a good probability to happen.

So when splitting to "WANT" & "A", the app will see that "WANT" has a good probability to happen, same for "A", then he will check the bigram compatibilitty which is also good. Even trigrams with "I" and "CAT" for more precision.

I guess it's a good solution which doesn't require a lot of time and which will be, I hope, kinda efficient.

I hope I made myself clear, and help people  who were wondering same questions.